# HTTPS urls don't onebox in chat

Tags: bug, chat, onebox, ssl

When posting an HTTPS url like `https://stackoverflow.com/...`, it does not onebox in chat.

For example: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12317079#12317079

Comment: Same for xkcd: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210585/xkcd-oneboxing-over-https

Comment: [Fixed on intra-SE posts](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2411172#2411172), doesn't look like it's fixed anywhere else (i.e. XKCD).