# XKCD oneboxing over HTTPS

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox, ssl

When posting an xkcd link in chat, it doesn't get oneboxed when using the https version of the URI:

[`http://xkcd.com/660/`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/13386994#13386994)

vs

[`https://xkcd.com/660/`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/13386996#13386996)

The first one gets oneboxed, but the latter just displays the link.