# Oneboxing a Stack Exchange post using HTTPS does not work

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox, ssl

When you post a link from Stack Exchange into the chatbox using HTTPS, the link does not onebox. However, if you change the link to HTTP, it works. See the screenshot below:

[image]

HTTPS URLs should onebox, too.

Comment: Eh, the original is two years old - and was written before we started rolling https out network wide. Kinda inclined to leave this one, when links turn into HTTPS, oneboxing is going to need love.

Comment: @Tim so maybe make that older request dupe of this one? Essentially these are both the same thing after all.

Comment: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." -> the old one doesn't have an answer.. I don't know how to handle these stuff _(old dupes)_. I don't care if this one gets closed.. but I just want to get the attention of the devs regarding this..

Comment: Reopened and flipped the close, where I also notice that using https links in the field where you put the question breaks as well.

Comment: @TimPost You think you could reach out to any of the SO people by any chance? There is also the issue of [other https links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210585/xkcd-oneboxing-over-https) not one boxing in general. *And* the fact that on main there is also still non https content on the page (e.g. imgur). Or can I create a new question with all the https stuff which is likely to get closed as a dupe of some other question(s).

Comment: @PeeHaa They're aware of it, I'll see what I can find out early next week.

Comment: @Oded this is not [tag:status-completed]. HTTPS links (I've observed xkcd)  still do not onebox.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - they mostly do. I think this may happen with timeouts to the source server (more common with HTTPS). A page refresh will normally show things oneboxed.